# HTML5 published and modified time

Tags: html, date, semantic-markup

I’d like to include published and modified time of an article. I looked through documentation and cannot find info about this.

So far, I got this:

```html
<article>                           
  <h2>Summer</h2>
  <p>Also the favorite word of <strong>5000</strong> people more</p>
  <time pubdate="2009-11-13">1s</time>
  <time datetime="2009-11-13">10s</time>
</article>
```

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/time-and-data-element/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) can’t have a `pubdate` attribute. (It was part of early drafts, but it got removed.)

HTML5 itself doesn’t provide a way to specify that a date is a publication or a modification date.

If you need to specify this in a machine-readable way, you could use an appropriate vocabulary. For example, the vocabulary [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) defines the properties [`datePublished`](http://schema.org/datePublished) and [`dateModified`](http://schema.org/dateModified) for [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) (and its sub-types).

Comment: examples please

Answer (score 0):

[dokieli](https://dokie.li/) is using

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
<head><title>demo</title></head>
<body>

<time
 datatype="xsd:dateTime"
 property="schema:dateModified"
 datetime="2016-02-06T00:00:00Z"
 content="2016-02-06T00:00:00Z"
>2016-02-06</time>

</body></html>
```

see [full example](https://csarven.ca/cooling-down-web-science)